# Аналог регулярного выражения или обратная функция str_replace

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть функция `str_replace`

```
$slovo = str_replace("s", "", $slovo);
```

Чтобы ни было в переменной - `str_replace` выбросит из нее буквы "s", если они там есть.

Интересует обратная ей функция. Что-то вроде аналога регулярного выражения. т.е. допустим:

```
$slovo = "oewiu*f037hf0287uhf08quh8uqen0f7320fn";
$only  = "h12}*"; // символы которые нужно оставить
// танцы с бубном
$slovo = "*hhh2";
```

Подскажите, как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace('/[^h12}*]/', '', 'oewiu*f037hf0287uhf08quh8uqen0f7320fn');
```

Comment: спасибо огромное